# add dot when mouse click for mapping

Tags: jquery, html, css

i am new with jquery algorithm, i want to ask, can i add dot or line when i my mouse click. so i know i already mark it or not. i want to use it for mapping on an image.
thanks

```
$(document).ready(function(e) { 
var coords = [];
var temp;
$('#map').click(function(e) {
    var posX = $(this).offset().left, posY = $(this).offset().top;
    var temp =((e.pageX - posX)+ ',' + (e.pageY - posY));
    coords.push(temp);
    if(coords.length == 1){
        $('#coords').attr({
            "shape"  : "rect",
            /*"style"  : "position:absolute; width: 2px; height: 2px; top: "posY"px; left: "posX"px; background: red;",*/
            "coords" : coords
        });
    }
    else {
        $('#coords').attr({
            "shape"  : "poly",
          //  "style"  : "position:absolute; width: 100px; height: 100px; background: red;",
            "coords" : coords
        });
    };
   });

$('#ret').click(function(e){
    coords.pop(temp);
    });

$('#del').click(function(e){
    coords.length=0;
});

$('#show').click(function(e){
    console.log(coords);
});
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/senryu/tdt8we0k/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve it following way.

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
       $("#maping").click(function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       var x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
       var y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
       var img = $('<img>');
       img.css('top', y);
       img.css('left', x);
       img.attr('width', 20);
       img.attr('height', 20);
       img.attr('src', 'http://www.clker.com/cliparts/q/p/u/5/b/3/green-leaf-icon-hi.png');
       img.appendTo('#maping');
     })
  });
```

```css
#maping{
    background: pink; 
    width: 1000px; 
    height: 500px; 
    position: relative;
}
#maping img {
    position: absolute;   
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="maping">

</div>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks @Richard Parnaby-King I was editing that part only.